# Optimize search in sourcecode using BufferedReader

Tags: java, url, search, bufferedreader

I've put some lines Java together and get a "programm" that read the sourcecode of a website and search line by line via BufferedReader the String Suche, copy the URL's in clipboard and give a message via JOptionPane if there is a match. All in all it work's great, but there is a problem: the perfomance. 
It's mostly because of my network latency I think.

At first, here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.net.URL; 

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Verbindung { 
 static String links ="";
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String[] urls = {"http://google.de"};
    for(int i=0; i < urls.length; i++ ){
    try { 
        URL url = new URL(urls[i]); 
        show(url); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    }
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
            new StringSelection(links), null);
    if (links != ""){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es wurden Links gefunden!");
    }
} 

private static void show(URL url) throws IOException{ 
    InputStream in = url.openStream(); 
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
    String s; 
    while ((s = buff.readLine()) != null) { 
            if(s.indexOf(Suche) != -1){
                links += url;

            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Edit: 
Theres is the nice idea from RealSkeptic to insert a break and close the reading after having a match, but there isn't a big different of perfomance. 
There are some more ideas to improve the perfomance of getting the Sourcecode (not including get a higher downloadspeed :D) or do it a better way?

Best regards from Germany.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the bottleneck is on the local machine, given that you're fetching over the network - the network latency will be far more significant.

Comment: One thing that may improve it is - since you are only interested in the fact that the URL contains the word, not how many times or anything - is to break out of the while (and close the reader!) as soon as you found a match.

Comment: Thanks, I've delete the lines after InputStream in show(URL url) and it seems to be only a litte different between this time and the time it takes to run my hole code. Is there a possibility to get only some lines of the sourcecode (f.e. using a method of URL)? What I specially mean: The code have some hundred lines and I only need fifty - hundred of lines where I want to search. Thanks a lot @RealSkeptic, nice idea!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "delete the lines after InputStream". Please click the "edit" button and edit your question to match your changes. And no, there is no way to select particular lines. The output from an HTTP server is just a stream of bytes.